# How to perform Collision detection between strokeBounds

Tags: paperjs

Here is the simplified form of my intention: [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

I only want the alert box turn to red when the orange circle is close enough (when the gray circle touches) to the line:

[image]

However, currently it may throw false alarms, ie. before close enough:

[image]

How can we correctly detect collisions?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to perform intersection detection on *dilated (expanded/offset)* paths, with the dilation equal to the amount of `strokeWidth`. There are some active discussions for this [outlined here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371).

Comment: Correct. I'll use this functionality for something like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzro0Jc70xI See how the trace routes push each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with "trial and error" approach: [Full example](https://github.com/ceremcem/paperjs-collision-test/blob/master/demo.js)

```js
// Returns item.position at the moment of collision
// and the collided object.
function collisionTest(item, curr){
    var prev = item.position;
    var point = curr.clone();
    var hit = null;
    var tolerance = 45;
    var _error = 0.01;
    var firstPass = true;
    var _stopSearching = false;
    var _step = ((curr - prev) / 2).clone();
    var _acceptable_iter_count = 16;
    var _max_iter_count = 100;

    var i; 
    for (i = 0; i < _max_iter_count; i++){
        var _hit = project.hitTest(point, {
            fill: true, 
            stroke: true, 
            segments: true, 
            tolerance: tolerance,
            match: function(hit){
                if (hit.item && hit.item.data && hit.item.data.type === "pointer"){
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }
        })

        if(_hit){
            hit = _hit;
            // hit has happened between prev and curr points 
            // step half way backward
            point -= _step 
            if (_step.length < _error){
                // step is too small, stop trials as soon 
                // as no hit can be found
                _stopSearching = true;
            }
        } else {
            if(firstPass || _stopSearching){
                break;
            } else  {
                // not hit found, but we should 
                // step forward to search for a more 
                // accurate collision point 
                point += _step  
            }
        }
        firstPass = false;
        if(_step.length >= _error * 2 ) {
            _step /= 2
        } else {
            // minimum step length must be error/2
            // in order to save loop count 
            _step = _step.normalize(_error * 0.8)
        }
    }
    if (i > _acceptable_iter_count){
        console.log("found at " + i + ". iteration, step: ", _step.length)
    }
    return {point, hit}
}
```

#### Algorithm

1. Perform a hit test.
2. If a hit is found, consider that the actual collision might happen anywhere between previous position and current position (on the `delta`).
3. Step backwards by `delta = delta / 2` and perform a hit test.
4. If still hits, repeat step 3.
5. If hit can not be found, step forward by `delta = delta / 2`
6. If still doesn't hit, repeat step 5.
7. If hits, repeat step 3 if step8 allows to do so.
8. If step size (`delta`) is too small or process exceeds max iteration limit, break and return the best possible collision point (the point for the item that provides best collision point)

## Further Improvements

This solution is based on the following problem: Detecting a hit is *not enough*, because it might be too late when the hit is detected and actual collision might be happened anywhere between previous and current points (on the `delta`) due to hit detection intervals.

This trial and error approach might be improved by starting the tries on a very accurate "guess" based on a proper calculation *after detecting the first hit*.

We can possibly calculate `1` (the actual collision point) in one shot by using `2`. It seems like it's the nearest point of `3` to `4`:

[image]

If the calculation is correct, only 2 loops would be enough to detect a collision point: 1st is for detecting the hit (as shown by `#2`) and 2nd is for verification. If it's not correct, trial-and-error approach will take over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Path.getIntersections()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections-path) or [`Path.intersects()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#intersects-item).

Comment: `getIntersections()` can not get intersections on `Path`s' boundaries (it doesn't take `strokeWidth` into account). Also, it's not clear how we can calculate the collision point, see `FIXME Sketch` in my edited question.

Comment: Link is hidden inside history, see **Edit** header of: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53017518/2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to find the direct intersections, you can instead find the [*nearest point*](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getnearestpoint-point) on the path from the position of the moving dot.

If the distance between the dot and that nearest point drops below a threshold (equal to the `strokeWidth` of the `Path` and the radius of the dot), then you can consider it a valid hit.

**There's a catch though**: The [`strokeJoin`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokejoin) & [`strokeCap`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokecap) properties of your path should be
set to `round`, since that results in a symmetrical stroke width around
corners and endings, hence avoiding false-negatives.

Here's an example:

```
var path = new Path({
    segments: [
        new Point(100, 200),
        new Point(200, 100),
        new Point(300, 300)
    ],
    strokeWidth: 100,
    // This is important.
    strokeJoin: 'round',
    // This is important.
    strokeCap: 'round',
    strokeColor: 'red',
    selected: true,
    position: view.center
})

var dot = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: 'red'
})

function onMouseMove(event) {
    dot.position = event.point

    var nearestPoint = path.getNearestPoint(dot.position)
    var distance = dot.position.subtract(nearestPoint)

    if (distance.length < (dot.bounds.width / 2) + (path.strokeWidth / 2)) {
        path.strokeColor = 'blue'
    } else {
        path.strokeColor = 'red'
    }
}
```

and the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jVPBboMwDP0Vi0tBq1La3dB26m1Sp0mbtEPpIYBbotIEJYEeqv77nABrNm3aEELg957tPJtLJPkJoyx6PaIt62gelapy3z3X0HJbwyNIPMMLvcaXXAJdBg8nlNZksB0C7vIkJaSNl2k6h1WaJvOf0JVDl7+h9w6lRzKAu5FkrFZHfBeVrTMnHsOLBbzVwoC7T63SlkvLQsUTJc1gplUnq9l/RWvefteMgGqUdhDeAGywtFhlYHWHY7BVRlihqHIv8MxK8gp1Lq90qFw6XytlA1vZWuiywcndgf5FO+bVvBKdcQaMgb1omrCpqca+k6VrAJTcqM7gRvUYY0+5EhirUAts6pN68SAFaAYugWO4RiVyjcb62RDL7QM7oH0OwnGYKblJK2HI2RJJFjKY6QqreWnjMHcyFRV7iCcla1AeaAEfwNco3EAMO7slgAWsEriD2HcUbIcHPg/ph3FjeKuon1nRdDgbKFfAxuBfgsFczyePc0m/SaGRH71hJsq2u+sH).

---

That being said, the best way to go about it is to wait for (or implement yourself), [Path dilation/offsetting](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371) and find the intersection on the dilated path instead, since this will allow you to use any `strokeJoin`/`strokeCap` setting.

Ideally the dilation/offsetting would be done with the same `strokeJoin`/`strokeCap` properties of the `Path`.

There's a [JS library that reliably does polygon offsetting](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) which might be of use to you.

Comment: Path offsetting seems promising on this topic. Actually what I'm trying to do is exactly offsetting the path and getting the intersections. On the other hand, deciding a hit is only the half of the solution because it might be too late when we detect a hit (exact hit point may be anywhere on `event.delta`). That's why, we need a function that calculates exact collision point *after* hit.